# Referencing a particular element in a list in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, jinja2

I am trying to copy the elements of one list to another, and i am using this piece of code to do that:

```
{% for i in range(2,7) %}
    {{ list1.append(list2|lookup:i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

list1 is an empty list.
I have also defined this custom filter lookup like this:

```
@register.filter
def lookup(d, key):
    return d[key]
```

But this does not work , I am getting this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at / expected token ',', got ':'.
```

What am i doing wrong. I am new to django and jinja template.

Comment: See [custom jinja2 filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters), and jinja2 filter uses function like syntax, `lookup:i` should be `lookup(i)`

Comment: lookup(i) does not work.

Comment: You first need to implement correctly, it seems you are implementing it like django template and expecting it to behave like jinja2. Follow the link I gave you and implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to call the method `append` with arguments which is not allowed in Django templates. You should write your own tag with the logic you need. For example:

```
list2|copy
```

Comment: I tried this as well :  {{ read_list.append(read_notifications.i) }} but this did not work whereas when i wrote  {{read_list.append(read_notifications.0)}} it worked

Comment: may be not in django template, but in jinja2 it's allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that filter with this simple lambda:

```
list1 + filter(lambda x: x if x not in list1 else None, range(2,7))
```

Comment: If you want to store the value use `+=` instead of `+`