# Forloop in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

How could I get a next object in django for loop?

I mean is it possible to do like this `{{ route.segments.all.ind }}`?

```
{% for segment in route.segments.all %}
     {% if segment.departure == departure %}
           {% with  forloop.counter as ind  %}
                <span style="margin-top: -5px; font-size: smaller">
                        $ {{ route.segments.all.ind }}
                        {{ segment.distance }}km
                        {{ segment.duration }}hour</span>               
            {%endwith %}
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: create a custom template filter to lookup a list by variable index. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658280/referencing-a-particular-element-in-a-list-in-django)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing a particular element in a list in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658280/referencing-a-particular-element-in-a-list-in-django)